# Probability density function of a Gamma random variable plus a constant

Tags: gamma-distribution

Suppose $X$ has a Gamma distribution $\Gamma(a,b)$. What is the distribution of $X+c$? where $c$ is a positive constant.

EDIT: I know how extract the expression of the pdf and cdf. What I wanted to know is if the resulting distribution is a know one.

Comment: It might be called a shifted Gamma distribution.

Comment: If $X$ has density function $f_X(x)$ and cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ then $Y=X+c$ has density function $f_Y(y)=f_X(y-c)$ and cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)=F_X(y-c)$

Comment: I don't understand how this question **without any personal work** can be upvoted and answered whereas sometimes downvotes accumulate on questions showing reflection... but estimated too naive maybe...

Comment: @JeanMarie, I know how extract the expression of the pdf and cdf. What I wanted to know is if the resulting distribution is a know one.

Comment: Then say it in this way in your question (I see you have added it)

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
& \Pr(X+c\le x) = \Pr(X\le x-c) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^{x-c} f(u)\, du \text{ if } x-c\ge0 \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_c^x f(v-c)\, dv \\[8pt]
& \text{where} \\
& v = u+c \\
& dv = dx \\
\text{so that } & \text{when } u=x-c \text{ then } v= c \\
\text{and } & \text{when } u=0 \text{ then } v=c.
\end{align}
So the probability density of $X+c$ is
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x-c) & \text{for } x>c, \\ 0 & \text{for }x<c. \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Simply

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}(y-c)^{a-1}e^{-(y-c)b}$$

$y\in[c;+\infty)$